# FFMPEG - convert files while being recorded

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, live, flv

I'm currently trying to stream a live video. I'm equipped with CCTV camera and a generic microphone. I'm using newest FFMPEG 1.0 (compiled from sources). Unfortunately, my camera provides only video stream, so I have to join it with audio manually. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# record mic input to wav file
arecord -f dat -D hw:0,0 mic.wav &

# record camera stream to avi file
cvlc rtsp://192.168.0.11:554/VideoInput/1/h264/1 --sout "#standard{access=file,mux=avi,dst=camera.avi}" &

# wait few seconds for both sources to stabilize
sleep 5

# join avi and wav to one flv file, then stram it to tcp socket (which is received by crtmpserver and transmitted forward to the website)
ffmpeg -i camera.avi -vcodec flv -i mic.wav -acodec mp3 -s 1280x720 -ar 44100 -ab 192k -vb 3000k -f flv - | ffmpeg -re -i - -codec copy -metadata streamName=streamhd tcp://127.0.0.1:6666 &
```

This code works and stream is being received for less than 5 seconds. If I increase sleep time, playback lasts longer. FFMPEG seems to convert only as much data as it receives in the beginning.

**How to force further conversion?**

I've tried named pipes. FFMPEG can't recognize input format then.

Comment: Why do you not use the mic and camera as direct inputs for ffmpeg?

Comment: Mic is working flawlessly, but for some unknown reason FFMPEG doesn't handle RTSP protocol correctly. I've tried also mencoder, only VLC works here.
FFMPEG=joins a/v, but doesn't work with camera
VLC=works with camera, but doesn't join a/v
MENCODER=couldn't get even mic working.

Comment: Did you refer to the [RTSP section](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#rtsp) of the docs? Are you using a recent build? The complete console output would be useful.